# Function that converts to number as well loop through all the grid sizes in vuejs

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, grid

I am creating a grid-system from scratch in Vuejs and have created different components for it, In my gridCol.vue component I have some props that takes both String and numbers
and have created a function for converting string to number inside my Computed() function.
So for example: if some one passes string instead of number, my function should convert it to number without any problem. But then I also want to do it for every props not just for 'Cols' props but also for xs/sm/md/lg/xl, How Can I do it ? Any help will be much Appreciated.

my gridCol.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class="col-container">
    <slot>
      <div class="col">{{ cols }}</div> // or sm/ md...
    </slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "GridCol",
  components: {},

  props: {
    cols: {
      type: [String, Number, Boolean],
      default: 12,
    },
    xs: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: 12,
    },
    sm: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: 12,
    },
    md: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: 6,
    },
    lg: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: 1,
    },
    xl: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: 1,
    },
    align: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    // converting string to numbe
    convertStringToNumber() {
      return this.cols ? parseInt(this.cols) : this.cols;
    },
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>
```

Comment: How do you want to use the converted number?

Comment: I didnot understand exactly what you mean but I will pass my props in App.vue like this:
 
<GridCol v-for="col in 1" :key="col" " xs="12" sm="12" md="6" lg="1">
          <Button variant="primary" label="I used full-width ( 12 columns)"></Button>
 </GridCol>

Comment: I mean inside the `gridCol` component

Comment: like this : <div class="col">{{ cols }}</div>

Comment: I think there's no need to convert